# How can i export a jar file with libraries in eclipse? (Not executable jar)

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

How can i export a jar file in eclipse with libraries? Executable jar wont work for me so that is out of the question. There is no option to do that when i try to export it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the jar is not running try to run it using a `CLI` for example command prompt `java -jar <name>.jar` and see the errors.

When you export the `.jar` there are **3** options .

- One and two produces the `.jar` with the libraries inside.
- Third option is producing a `.jar` (executable) with the libraries added
  a different folder[ which has the same name as the jar file and it
  must be named like it].

---

**Mention that:**

You may have serious problems and your executable will not run if your application has `duplicate entries`. So most of the time the third bullet is the best solution.

**Sample image:**

[image]

---

If you are trying to create a `.jar` to add it as a **library** to other projects then you should follow the below:

[image]

[image]

Comment: My code is meant as a script for an application. It does not have any main class, just a loop. I created a empty main method just so i can export it as an executable jar. The first "tick" option does not work, the jar file wont even show up in the application when i try select the jar. The second and the third option do not work either, i guess the application cant unpack the libs and or see the other folder.. Guess i will have to ask the application devs on how to do this

Comment: @David Minesote Can you add the code of your app?What external libraries are you using?Do you tried to run it with the command prompt?It is impossible no one of the ticks isn't working ... Some error is coming . Try run it using command prompt with `java -jar <name>.jar` and check if any errors are coming back.